# python import statement results in NoneType

Tags: python, django, import

Ok, so here's a simplified version of the thing that has been driving me crazy all day:

`models.py`:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ....

    def populate_property(self):
        self.property = slugify('string of text')
```

My view then calls `populate_property()` but I get a `NoneType object is not callable` error.

BUT, if I add an inline `import` of `slugify` then it works.

This is code that has worked for a long time, so I'm at a loss right now.

The `PYTHONPATH` but it looks ok and the environment is created using `buildout`

Any help would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having just conquered a similar issue, it sounds like you have a circular reference in your code (this file imports something that imports from this file). There's no harm in putting the import inside populate_property.

Comment: to be true it means that the circular import is caused somewhere in django.template.defaultfilters, it sounds a bit strange to me ... he also says that it happens when the method is called and not when the module is loaded.

Comment: That was essentially it, actually. Thanks, Tom. I was using a wildcard include where it wasn't necessary and that killed just about everything. [I should know better](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615125/should-wildcard-import-be-avoided).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you've posted, there should be no problems. The only thing I can think of to cause the error you mention is that a some point you changed the value of `slugify`. It was most likely accidental use of `=` when intending to use `==` or something similar.

The best way to check is to leave the rest of your code as is, but in addition to the import you have now, add `from django.template import defaultfilters`. Then, change the specific line of code in question to:

```
def populate_property(self):
    self.property = defaultfilters.slugify('string of text')
```

If it works, then try to track down the place where `slugify` got reassigned.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Chris. `defaultfilters` is also undefined. In fact most of the things that are not inline includes are undefined.

Comment: Is it only Django imports? Perhaps something went awry in Django package -- reinstalling it may help. If this behavior is occurring with stdlib imports as well, you whole environment may be borked. Do you have another system that you can test your code on? (Or try creating a new virtualenv if you're using that).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Django < 1.7, I noticed this is almost certainly due to a circular import caused by an `import signal`.
I always ended up with quirky situations where it works in local, maybe on dev server and probably not on prod server...