# Advantages of `from foo import spam` over `from foo import *`

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should wildcard import be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615125/should-wildcard-import-be-avoided)

What advantages does `from foo import spam` offer over `from foo import *` other than not importing every function?

Does it save memory? Or is it just syntactic sugar but actually imports everything? 
Where can I find more about it?

If it does save memory how does that work?

Comment: `from foo import *` will import everything in foo - global vars, methods, classes, includes that foo includes, whilst `from foo import spam` will only import `spam`. Imagine a module with hundreds of variables and methods - you want to only import `spam` to stop name conflicts, and help with performance and memory use

Comment: In order to answer one specific question (it is NOT an *exact* duplicate): Concerning memory, it doesn't make a difference. The import process is exactly the same, but the binding process afterwards is the difference.

Answer (score 3):

Polluting the global namespace with names you don't explicitly import is a bad idea. It makes is impossible to tell where names you use later in your code actually got imported from without going and reading the source of every module that's been imported, and risks two modules using the same names, which will probably break things.

Answer (score 2):

Importing * would import every thing present in the foo,
where as import spam would import only the required attributes.

It's is like having unused variables/methods in the code.
If you begin to rate your code using something like pylint, having unused variables and method lowers the rating

Answer (score 1):

If you need everything or most of `foo` then `from foo import *` is better, but if you need only `spam` then `from foo import spam` would do the job for you.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from other reasons, one thing the import of form:

   `from foo import spam`

helps is that it improves the code readability. By looking at the above statement it is clear what dependency current module has on module foo.