# How do I read code where "from <module> import *" is used?

Tags: python, import, module, readability

Suppose I read code written by someone else where "from  import *" is used, how can I determine what module a function is from?  Is this the reason why some people frown upon "from  import *"?

Comment: This may be a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3615206/770830

Comment: go into a python shell, run the (admittedly bad-style) import *, then do str(function) - this will tell you which module it's coming from... then replace with proper imports ;)

Comment: I just did this.. it doesn't seem to do what you say.

Comment: `str` won't do the trick. What you can do is look at the `__module__` of each function, e.g. `from urllib2 import urlopen; urlopen.__module__` → `'urllib2'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is why `from <module> import *` is considered bad style. What you can do is remove these `*` imports one by one, then check which `NameError`s you get and solve them one by one by explicit imports.

Comment: Good idea. This falls down of course if the `from <m> import *` happens to overwrite some object's name in the local namespace. Then you'd get all possible kinds of errors after removing the `import` statement. Which is yet another reason not to use this construct.

Answer (score 3):

`from ... import *` is the bad style not recommended by [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (python style guide). There are no ways to know which module is function from except the editing the code (replacing `from ... impot *` to 'import ...' and looking for errors). Unfortunately, those errors will occur only when corresponding parts of code is executed.