# How should I indent the import of many classes from single module

Tags: python, python-import

If I need import some `Class1`, `Class2`, ... , `ClassN` from module `module`, how should I indent it?

```
from module import (
    Class1,
    Class2,
    ...
    ClassN
)
```

or maybe

```
from module import (
    Class1, Class2, ...,
    ..., ClassN
)
```

Can't find any information in PEP specification.

Comment: As long as you're consistent, any of the line continuation styles from the PEP is OK. One per line will take up a lot of vertical space, though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a recommended format for multi-line imports?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376900/is-there-a-recommended-format-for-multi-line-imports)

Comment: But maybe some of this is prefered or looks cleaner?

Comment: @Pycz how could that be anything but opinion-based?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ok, thanks, I just thought about some common practices...

Answer (score 2):

If the number of classes you import is higher, you should consider importing only their parent module, and access the classes through it, like:

```
import module

module.Class1
module.Class2
```

On the other hand, if there really aren't that many classes, but still exceeds the 80 char limit, I usually import using the following style:

```
from module import (Class1,
                    Class2,
                    Class3,
                    Class4)
```