# Difference between import tkinter as tk and from tkinter import

Tags: python, import, tkinter

I know it is a stupid question but I am just starting to learn python and i don't have good knowledge of python. My question is what is the difference between

```
from Tkinter import *
```

and

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

?Why can't i just write

```
import Tkinter
```

Could anyone spare a few mins to enlighten me?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`from Tkinter import *` imports every exposed object in Tkinter into your current namespace.
`import Tkinter` imports the "namespace" Tkinter in your namespace and 
`import Tkinter as tk` does the same, but "renames" it locally to 'tk' to save you typing

let's say we have a module foo, containing the classes A, B, and C.

Then `import foo` gives you access to foo.A, foo.B, and foo.C.

When you do `import foo as x` you have access to those too, but under the names x.A, x.B, and x.C.
`from foo import *` will import A, B, and C directly in your current namespace, so you can access them with A, B, and C.

There is also `from foo import A, C` wich will import A and C, but not B into your current namespace.

You can also do `from foo import B as Bar`, which will make B available under the name Bar (in your current namespace).

So generally: when you want only one object of a module, you do `from module import object` or `from module import object as whatiwantittocall`.

When you want some modules functionality, you do `import module`, or `import module as shortname` to save you typing.

`from module import *` is discouraged, as you may accidentally shadow ("override") names, and may lose track which objects belong to wich module.

Comment: So, does it take more processing power to use "import foo" if i am only gonna use one class (eg. class A). Should i use the "from foo import A" instead? or the difference is negligible? Btw, Great explanation for a beginner like me. thanks!

Comment: Performance concerns about imports are a) negligible and b) irrelevant. Do what suits you best, not the python implementation. 'from foo import A' is faster in the lookup later when you use A, but pythonists generally don't care about such things.

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly use

```
import Tkinter
```

However, if you do that, you'd have to prefix every single Tk class name you use with `Tkinter.`.

This is rather inconvenient.

On the other hand, the following:

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

sidesteps the problem by only requiring you to type `tk.` instead of `Tkinter.`.

As to:

```
from Tkinter import *
```

it is generally a bad idea, for reasons discussed in [Should wildcard import be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615125/should-wildcard-import-be-avoided)

Answer (score 0):

Writing:

```
from tkinter import *
```

results in importing everything  that exists in `tkinter` module

Writing:

```
import tkinter
```

results in importing `tkinter` module but if you do so, in order to be able to call any method you will have to use:

```
tkinter.function_name()
```