# Getting error when importing Tkinter and making a window

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is my code guys:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
theLabel = Label(root, 'Hello World')
theLabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Here is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/argel/PycharmProjects/day2/rockpaper.py", line 4, in
>   
>       theLabel = Label(root, 'Hello World')   File "C:\Users\argel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py",
>   line 2760, in **init**
>       Widget.**init**(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)   File "C:\Users\argel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py",
>   line 2289, in **init**
>       classes = [(k, v) for k, v in cnf.items() if isinstance(k, type)] AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Thank you for your help

Comment: Maybe you want `Label(root, text='Hello World')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `theLabel = Label(root, 'Hello World')` to `theLabel = Label(root, text='Hello World')` and it will work.

I have a suggestion to improve your code:

Rather than `from tkinter import *` use `import tkinter as tk`.

`from tkinter import *` is actually discouraged so I strongly recommend you do **not** use this method.

Remember you would also need to change your script slightly if you do.  It would look like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
theLabel = tk.Label(root, text='Hello World')
theLabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

For more information the differences between imports please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974787/difference-between-import-tkinter-as-tk-and-from-tkinter-import) post.

I hope it solved your problem.