# How to lay-out a matplotlib bar graph in python tkinter that is irregularly positioned, not conforming to a 3x3 grid

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

The following python code displays a bar graph behind two scrolledtext boxes and a number of buttons. I'm really new at doing **python** and I'd like to know whether it's possible to resize the graph so that:

(1) its left edge is aligned with the right edges of the ***scrolledtext boxes***;

(2) its top is aligned with the top of ***button 3***;

(3) its bottom is aligned with the bottom edge of the ***lower scrolledtext box***; and,

(4) its right edge is aligned with the right edge of the ***screen***.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import Button
from tkinter import scrolledtext as tkst
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

def dummy():
    return

ww = tkinter.Tk()
ww.geometry('700x400')
ww.state('zoomed')

datalst = [31, 41, 59, 26, 53, 58, 97, 96, 36]
ff = Figure(figsize=(6,6), dpi=100)
xx = ff.add_subplot(111)
ind = np.arange(len(datalst))
rects1 = xx.bar(ind, datalst, 0.8)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(ff, master=ww)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

butt1 = Button(ww,text='Button 1',command=dummy, height=1,width=20,state='normal')
butt1.place(x=12, y=2)
butt2 = Button(ww,text='Button 2',command=dummy, height=1,width=20,state='disabled')
butt2.place(x=162, y=2)
butt3 = Button(ww,text='Button 3',command=dummy, height=1,width=10,state='disabled')
butt3.place(x=320, y=100)
butt4 = Button(ww,text='Button 4',command=dummy, height=1,width=10,state='disabled')
butt4.place(x=320, y=128)
butt5 = Button(ww,text='Button 5',command=dummy, height=1,width=10,state='disabled')
butt5.place(x=320, y=156)
butt6 = Button(ww,text='Button 6',command=dummy, height=1,width=10,state='disabled')
butt6.place(x=320, y=184)
butt7 = Button(ww,text='Button 7',command=dummy, height=1,width=12,state='disabled')
butt7.place(x=420, y=394)
butt8 = Button(ww,text='Button 8',command=dummy, height=1,width=12,state='disabled')
butt8.place(x=600, y=394)

disp_txt1 = tkst.ScrolledText(ww, width=36, height=12, wrap=tkinter.WORD, state='disabled')
disp_txt1.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH)
disp_txt1.place(x=410, y=100)
disp_txt2 = tkst.ScrolledText(ww, width=36, height=5, wrap=tkinter.WORD, state='disabled')
disp_txt2.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH)
disp_txt2.place(x=410, y=300)

ww.mainloop()
```

The orange rectangle below shows where I intend the graph to be:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that import `tkinter as tk` .Note that is always good to import `tkinter` this way as it doesn't import `namespaces` [importing tkinter as tk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974787/difference-between-import-tkinter-as-tk-and-from-tkinter-import).

The was not the error the you need to specify where you want to position the `widget` as `pack` position it at middle of the available space in the window.
To do that use `canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.RIGHT)` which means right hand side of the screen. You can check the documentation for the attribute.

**FULL CODE**

```
from tkinter import scrolledtext as tkst
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as tk


matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

def dummy():
    return

ww = tk.Tk()
ww.geometry('700x400')
ww.state('zoomed')

datalst = [31, 41, 59, 26, 53, 58, 97, 96, 36]
ff = Figure(figsize=(6,6), dpi=100)
xx = ff.add_subplot(111)
ind = np.arange(len(datalst))
rects1 = xx.bar(ind, datalst, 0.8)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(ff, master=ww)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

butt1 = tk.Button(ww,text='Button 1',command=dummy, height=1,width=20,state='normal')
butt1.place(x=12, y=2)
butt2 = tk.Button(ww,text='Button 2',command=dummy, height=1,width=20,state='disabled')
butt2.place(x=162, y=2)
butt3 = tk.Button(ww,text='Button 3',command=dummy, height=1,width=10,state='disabled')
butt3.place(x=320, y=100)
butt4 = tk.Button(ww,text='Button 4',command=dummy, height=1,width=10,state='disabled')
butt4.place(x=320, y=128)
butt5 = tk.Button(ww,text='Button 5',command=dummy, height=1,width=10,state='disabled')
butt5.place(x=320, y=156)
butt6 = tk.Button(ww,text='Button 6',command=dummy, height=1,width=10,state='disabled')
butt6.place(x=320, y=184)
butt7 = tk.Button(ww,text='Button 7',command=dummy, height=1,width=12,state='disabled')
butt7.place(x=420, y=394)
butt8 = tk.Button(ww,text='Button 8',command=dummy, height=1,width=12,state='disabled')
butt8.place(x=600, y=394)

disp_txt1 = tkst.ScrolledText(ww, width=36, height=12, wrap=tk.WORD, state='disabled')
disp_txt1.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)
disp_txt1.place(x=410, y=100)
disp_txt2 = tkst.ScrolledText(ww, width=36, height=5, wrap=tk.WORD, state='disabled')
disp_txt2.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)
disp_txt2.place(x=410, y=300)

ww.mainloop()
```

[image]