# Position childs inside a paned window

Tags: python, tkinter, sticky

I'm trying to implement a resizable window with some widgets inside it, some of which should be centered and some left-justified. Currently, all widgets are centered:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.resizable()
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
x_cordinate = int((screen_width / 2) - (300 / 2))
y_cordinate = int((screen_height / 2) - (200 / 2))
root.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(300, 200, x_cordinate, y_cordinate))
root.title("Pane Sticky Test")

main_pane = PanedWindow(root, orient=VERTICAL)
main_pane.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

var = IntVar()

# check = Checkbutton(main_pane, text="My option", variable=var, sticky=W) --> error unknown option "-sticky"
check = Checkbutton(main_pane, text="My option", variable=var)
main_pane.add(check)

# label = Label(main_pane, text="Preview:", sticky=W) --> error unknown option "-sticky"
label = Label(main_pane, text="Preview:")
main_pane.add(label)

entry = Text(main_pane, height=10, width=50)
main_pane.add(entry)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: Result]

I want to place my option check box and my preview label left-justified. I read in [this documentation](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/pane-options.html), there should be a sticky option that "functions like the sticky argument to the .grid() method." But this option does not work (see the two lines I commented out).

Is there a way to place some widgets left-justified or right-justified inside a vertically oriented paned window in tkinter? I'm using tkinter version 8.6 with Tcl/Tk version 8.6.9 on windows.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option called `anchor` whihc functions similar to `sticky`

Add `anchor` parameter for the widget. e.g -

```
check = Checkbutton(main_pane, text="My option", variable=var,anchor=W)
```

You will see that the check button is towards the left.

The final code -

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.resizable()
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
x_cordinate = int((screen_width / 2) - (300 / 2))
y_cordinate = int((screen_height / 2) - (200 / 2))
root.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(300, 200, x_cordinate, y_cordinate))
root.title("Pane Sticky Test")

main_pane = PanedWindow(root, orient=VERTICAL)
main_pane.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

var = IntVar()

check = Checkbutton(main_pane, text="My option", variable=var,anchor=W)
main_pane.add(check)

label = Label(main_pane, text="Preview:",anchor=W)
main_pane.add(label)

entry = Text(main_pane, height=10, width=50)
main_pane.add(entry)
root.mainloop()
```

And do not use * for import. More recommended is this way - `import tkinter as tk` i.e using alias import

Reference - [anchor](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_anchors.htm#:%7E:text=Python%20%2D%20Tkinter%20Anchors,-Advertisements&text=Anchor%20NW%20will%20position%20the,that%20point%2C%20and%20so%20on.) and [why use `import tkinter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974787/difference-between-import-tkinter-as-tk-and-from-tkinter-import)

Answer (score -1):

> I want to place my option check box and my preview label
> left-justified.

The problem can be fixed.

Avoid wildcard *. Use `import tkinter as tk`, then do `tk.` prefix

You are missing several `pack()` manager layout.

Add this line 34 to 36 before `mainloop()`.

Snippet, there are no minor changes, Just added 3 pack():
import tkinter as tk

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable()

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
x_cordinate = int((screen_width / 2) - (300 / 2))
y_cordinate = int((screen_height / 2) - (200 / 2))

root.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(300, 200, x_cordinate, y_cordinate))
root.title("Pane Sticky Test")

main_pane = tk.PanedWindow(root, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
 
var = tk.IntVar()

# check = Checkbutton(main_pane, text="My option", variable=var, sticky=W) --> error unknown option "-sticky"
check = tk.Checkbutton(main_pane, text="My option", variable=var)
main_pane.add(check)
 

# label = Label(main_pane, text="Preview:", sticky=W) --> error unknown option "-sticky"
label = tk.Label(main_pane, text="Preview:")
main_pane.add(label)
 
entry = tk.Text(main_pane, height=10, width=50)
 
main_pane.add(entry)

main_pane.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

check.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor='nw')
label.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor='nw')
entry.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor='nw',fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]