# Python import: Object has no attribute

Tags: python

I've continually looked up solutions to this and I can't find a simple answer. I'm trying to create an object from an imported class, and then call a method on that object.

```
from MySchedule import *
my_schedule = MySchedule(self.driver)
my_schedule.navigate_to_my_schedule() # getting an error here
```

Error is

```
AttributeError: MySchedule object has no attribute 'navigate_to_my_schedule'
```

Code from `MySchedule.py`:

```
class MySchedule:

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self.nav_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_id('locButton_1')
        self.header = self.driver.find_element_by_id('panelTitle_1')

    def navigate_to_my_schedule(self):
        self.nav_btn.click()
```

Comment: Are your `def` lines indented in your program, or are they (incorrectly) unindented like they are here?

Comment: @TheSoundDefense good catch, but no they are correct in my program. I'll go ahead and edit that.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using `MySchedule` as both the module name and the class name, and are using `from MySchedule import *`.

I'd recommend changing the `import` statement to

```
import MySchedule
```

and referring to the class as `MySchedule.MySchedule`.

For further discussion of wildcard imports, see [Should wildcard import be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615125/should-wildcard-import-be-avoided)

Comment: thanks. how could I avoid using something like MySchedule.MySchedule and just use MySchedule?

Comment: @logan_gabriel: Rename the module to `my_schedule` and import the class like so: `from my_schedule import MySchedule`.