# Python Multiple file program

Tags: python, python-2.7, coding-style

For larger programs, in order to be more organized, I have been looking into dividing my code up into different `.py` files and having the main file that calls upon those files when needed. I have looked around and seen lots of remarks about creating a directory and a `SystemPath` for Python. Are those reasonable options for a program that could be distributed between a few computers? As a test, I tried to assemble an example:

This is the class named `grades` in the same directory as `main`

```py
class student:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.score = 0
        self.grade = 0

    def update(self,name,score,grade):
        self.score = score
        self.name = name
        self.grade = grade
        print self.score,self.name,self.grade

s = student()
s.update(name,score,grade)
```

This is my main script currently:

```py
from grades import score
import random

name = 'carl'
score = random.randrange(0,100)
grade = 11

s = student()
s.score(name,score,grade)
```

There are some questions I have generally about this method:

1. Is there a way to import all from different files or do I need to specify each individual class?
2. If I just had a function, is it possible to import it just as a function or can you only import via a class?
3. Why is it when I call upon a class, in general, I have to make a variable for it as in the example below?

```py
# way that works
s = student()
s.update(name,score,grade)

# incorrect way
student.update(name,score,grade)
```

Thank you for your time and thought towards my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes.

You can import instance of `student` from other script to main script like this:

```
from grades import s
# if your first script is called grades.py
import random

name = 'carl'
score = random.randrange(0,100)
grade = 11
# you can directly use it without initializing it again.
s.score(name,score,grade)
```

2.
If you have a function called `test()` in grades.py, you can import it in this way:

```
from grades import test

# then invoke it
test()
```

3.
This variable stands for the instance of class student. You need this instance to invoke the function inside.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, to divide the source code of a program, Python use **module** to do that, which corresponds to a *.py file. Then for your 3 questions:

1. You can import a whole "module content" (function, class, global variables, ...) through `import module_name.*`
2. for a function, if it is a function in a class(member method, class method or static method) you can not only import the function, you should import class to use the method; if it is a function under module, you can separately import the function through import `module_name.function_name`
3. **update** is a member function of the student class, so you should use it through an instance. if it is a class method or static method, you can use it through the class name you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

> 1: Is there a way to import all from different file or do i need to
>   specify each individual class?

You can use the "wildcard import", but you probably shouldn't. See
[Should wildcard import be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615125/should-wildcard-import-be-avoided)

> 2. If i just had a function, is it possible to import it just as a
>      function or can you only import via a class?

Functions can be totally independent of classes in Python.

> 3.Why is it when i call upon a class in general i have to make a variable for it as in the example below?

You should read up on object-oriented programming. In the basic cases, you have to instantiate instances of a class in order to use that class's functionality. In your example, the class student describes what it means to be a student, and the statement

> s = student()

creates a student and names it "s".
I think this should be clear after reading a bit about object-oriented programming.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can use `from module import *` to import everything like:
hello.py:

```
def hello():
  print 'hello'

def bye():
  print 'Bye'
```

main.py:

```
from hello import *

hello()
bye()
```

But it's not a good way, if you have two files, two functions have the same name, 
so use

```
from hello import hello, bye

hello()
bye()
```

is better, it an example for function ,as same as class.

Third before Second,  student is a class, so you have to use an instance object to use the function which with self parameter. If you want to use student.function, the function must be a static method like this:

```
class Person:

  def __init__():
    pass

  @staticmethod
  def Count():
    return 1

print Person.Count()
```

Second, you can import the function in a class file which is independent of the class.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is there a way to import all from different file or do i need to specify each individual class?

the answer is yes , as python `import` statement use [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) (A list of strings that specifies the search path for modules ) you need to add the patht of your modules in `sys.path` , for example if you want to interact between different computers you can put your modules in `public` folder and add the path of folder to `sys.path` :

```
import sys
sys.path.append( path to public )
```

> 2. If i just had a function, is it possible to import it just as a function or can you only import via a class?

you just need to use `from ... import function_name`.

> 3. Why is it when i call upon a class in general i have to make a variable for it as in the example below?

for this question you just need to read the python [`Class objects`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) documentation :

> Class objects support two kinds of operations: attribute references and instantiation.