# i = self._randbelow(len(seq)) TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, typeerror

I have this error when I'm running my code for building a perfect maze.
Here is the code:

```
   def walk(self, s, x, y):

        neighboor = [(x + 1, y), (x - 1, y), (x, y + 1), (x, y - 1)]

        if s.size() == self.size**2: return

        else:

            while True:
                new = choice(neighboor)
                if self.is_valid(new[0], new[1]): break

            while self.maze[new[0]][new[1]].getVisit():

                if len(neighboor) != 0: new = choice(neighboor.remove(new))
                else:
                    temp = s.pop(s)
                    self.walk(s, temp[0], temp[1])

            #print(new)

            self.maze[new[0]][new[1]].changeVisit()
            if new == neighboor[1]:
                self.maze[x][y].changeNorth()
                self.maze[new[0]][new[1]].changeSouth()
            elif new == neighboor[0]:
                self.maze[x][y].changeSouth()
                self.maze[new[0]][new[1]].changeNorth()
            elif new == neighboor[2]:
                self.maze[x][y].changeEast()
                self.maze[new[0]][new[1]].changeWest()
            elif new == neighboor[3]:
                self.maze[x][y].changeWest()
                self.maze[new[0]][new[1]].changeEast()


            s.push(new)

            self.walk(s, new[0], new[1])
```

Here is the Error I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    a.search()
  File "C:\Users\Serena\Desktop\XAproject\Stack.py", line 93, in search
    self.walk(s, startX, startY)
  File "C:\Users\Serena\Desktop\XAproject\Stack.py", line 76, in walk
    self.walk(s, new[0], new[1])
  File "C:\Users\Serena\Desktop\XAproject\Stack.py", line 76, in walk
    self.walk(s, new[0], new[1])
  File "C:\Users\Serena\Desktop\XAproject\Stack.py", line 76, in walk
    self.walk(s, new[0], new[1])
  File "C:\Users\Serena\Desktop\XAproject\Stack.py", line 76, in walk
    self.walk(s, new[0], new[1])
  File "C:\Users\Serena\Desktop\XAproject\Stack.py", line 76, in walk
    self.walk(s, new[0], new[1])
  File "C:\Users\Serena\Desktop\XAproject\Stack.py", line 76, in walk
    self.walk(s, new[0], new[1])
  File "C:\Users\Serena\Desktop\XAproject\Stack.py", line 52, in walk
    if len(neighboor) != 0: new = choice(neighboor.remove(new))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\random.py", line 253, in choice
    i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

I think 'neighboor' is a list contains four sets of number, it should have len().

I'm new to programming, any help would be appreciate.

Comment: X, y r just two int represent the coordinates.

Comment: Aside - The spelling of neighboor here is actually [neighbor or neighbour](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbour)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple of things. First, if you're using something like choice() that's imported from a wildcard import (from random import *), it would be useful to include that, because otherwise we're just guessing where you got that function from. Also, [wildcard imports are considered bad practice anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615125/should-wildcard-import-be-avoided).

The problem is that the remove() method of a list returns None. You cannot choose something from None, because None is not an iterable. That is to say that the remove() method does not support chaining.
Try changing:

```
if len(neighboor) != 0: new = choice(neighboor.remove(new)) # Passes None to choice() which raises an error
```

to

```
if len(neighboor) != 0:
    neighboor.remove(new) # removes the element from neighboor
    new = choice(neighboor) # Chooses from the list as you intended
```

You could have other errors, but that's the one that came from the traceback you posted.

For the future, I recommend familiarizing yourself with Python's traceback, because it is telling you exactly what is going wrong. [Here's a resource](http://cbio.ufs.ac.za/live_docs/nbn_tut/understanding_errors.html).

As an aside, do you mean neighbor instead of neighboor?

Comment: Being picky, but it `choice` doesn't have to be from a wildcard import, it could have been imported with `from random import choice`.

Comment: Fair enough. I don't intend to edit it though, as I like to share that wildcard imports should generally be avoided and I still think the point about it being more difficult for answers to see what's going on is valid.

Comment: I also use other function from random, not only choice. and it's my first year in CS, I have no idea that wildcard import should be avoid. Thx for telling me and will improve it.