# from tkinter import * used; unable to detect undefined names in Spyder2 IDE

Tags: python, tkinter, anaconda, spyder

I installed Anaconda in my MacBookPro (OSX 10.11.4 El Capitan) and try to run the following program of Python3.5.1 using Spyder2;

```
from tkinter import *
import sys
win = Tk()
button = Button(win, text='Push this Button!', command=exit)
button.pack()
mainloop()
```

However, Spyder2 tells me "from tkinter import * used; unable to detect undefined names", I cannot run it under Spyder2. However, after saving it with the name of "Sample.py" and run it in the Terminal, I can run it successfully.
I suppose this error might be caused unresolved error in linker. Can you help me?
I also encountered this problem when I installed Anaconda in Windows10.

Thank you Bryan. I tried the following code in Spyder2;

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys
win=tk.Tk()
button=tk.Button(win,text="Goodbye",command=exit)
button.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

Then, it worked. However, still I do not understand why the original one did not work under Spyder 2, while it nicely worked under Bash.

Comment: Why are you using `from tkinter import *`? wildcard imports shouldn't be used. Use a normal import (eg: `import tkinter` or `import tkinter as tk`).

Comment: Here is a discussion on wildcard imports https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615125/should-wildcard-import-be-avoided

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spyder IDE complaining about unable to detect undefined names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50439309/spyder-ide-complaining-about-unable-to-detect-undefined-names)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same message. Like this I suppressed the wildcard. There is no error now. But keeps on not showing the form.

```py
import PyQt5

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from PyQt5 import QtGui

from PyQt5 import QtCore

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
```