# Spyder IDE complaining about unable to detect undefined names

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, spyder

Using Windows 10 with Spyder IDE running Python 3.5. I am seeing following in the `__init__.py` file complaining about `unable to detect undefined names`:

[image]

However, it seems `__init__.py` file is in the same folders as all other files.

[image]

So why it is complaining? I tried to remove the leading dot in the front, but it still complains. Please give me some pointers.

Comment: It is just complaining because of the `*`. Wants you to spell out explicitly which names you're importing from them...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your IDE is complaining, not Python. When you do `from simple import *`, you import *everything* exposed by `simple`. This is typically not recommended because it pollutes the global namespace and may implicitly overwrite an existing object.

You get a warning instead of an error because this behavior is not always bad. Having an `__init__.py` file that exposes objects from sub-modules is a very common pattern. As long as you understand the potential risks, just silence the warning:

```
from .input import *  # NOQA
```

If your modules don't expose many objects, just import them by name:

```
from .input import A, B, C
```

This has the benefit of allowing Python code analysis tools to better understand your code and warn you of potential issues.

Comment: What's meaning of `NOQA`?

Comment: @rvcristiand NO Quality Assurance

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem,
the asterisk.
I located the modules to call them as indicated by **Blender**

and it was solved

[image: One]

change the asterisk by the names of the modules

[image: Two]

locate the names that have conflict

[image: Three]

and as you add them up, the error will be silenced

[image: Four]

Thanks for your comments, they helped me with the problem I had