# Sum of variable got with a Radiobutton = 0

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, sum, radio-button

I'm trying to do a simple program using python but it doesn't work. In the penultimate string I don't know how to get the variable from the Radiobutton.

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter.messagebox

finestra = Tk()
finestra.geometry("1000x800+100+0")
finestra.title("Consumo PC")
var = IntVar()
ivar = IntVar()
cpu = Label(text="Seleziona la generazione del tuo processore:").pack()
kaby = Radiobutton(finestra,text="Kabylake",value=1, variable=var).pack()
sky = Radiobutton(finestra,text="SkyLake",value=2, variable=var).pack()
ivy = Radiobutton(finestra,text="IvyBridge",value=3, variable=var).pack()

serie = Label(text="Seleziona il tuo processore:").pack()
i3 = Radiobutton(finestra,text="i3 xxxx",value=6, variable=ivar).pack()
i5 = Radiobutton(finestra,text="i5 xxxx",value=4, variable=ivar).pack()
i7 = Radiobutton(finestra,text="i7 xxxx",value=5, variable=ivar).pack()

brand = Label(text="Seleziona il brand della tua scheda video:").pack()
amd = Radiobutton(finestra,text="AMD", value=7,variable=3).pack()
nvidia = Radiobutton(finestra,text="Nvidia", value=8,variable=3).pack()

kaby = 1
sky = 1
ivy = 11/10
i3 = 51
i5 = 65
i7 = 75

tdp = Label(text=var.get()+ivar.get()).pack()


finestra.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you are changing text of label *only* as soon as you create your UI and since none of those selected, you are getting 0. That text should update on every `var`/`ivar` change.

That can be achieved by adding [trace](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) for `var` and `ivar`.

```
def callback(*args):
    print(var.get()+ivar.get())

var.trace("w", callback)
ivar.trace("w", callback)
```

With this, on every button selection, you will get your desired value.

Now one thing left, which is updating the resul label. There are couple ways to update the text of label but since we are using variable classes, let's do it using `StringVar`.

```
def callback(*args):
    result.set(var.get()+ivar.get())

result = StringVar()

tdp = Label(textvariable=result).pack()
                ^^^^^^^^ note that this not text but textvariable!
```

Also, there are couple things you should be aware.

One of them is wildcard import (`from tkinter import *` usage).
About this one, you can read answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615125/should-wildcard-import-be-avoided) question.

Other one is, using `pack()` at the same line. That will assign `None` to all of your variables(`cpu`, `kaby`, `sky` etc.).
About this one, you can read answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-get) question.

Comment: I did as you said. But the addends are the values written in the Radio-Button row. As you can note I wanted to add the same values to Kaby and Sky. How can I do this? I'm still using from tkinter import owing to I don't know what I have to write under  - import tkinter -.

Comment: @T.Sala I don't think, I understand what you wanted but overall, if you want to do something when var/ivar change, you need to do it in `callback`.