# In Python, is it possible to round towards one direction when rounding to n decimal digits?

Tags: python

In Python, `round` can be used to round to n decimal digits. Now, `round(0.229, 1)` gives `0.2` and `round(0.251, 1)` gives `0.3`. Is there a way in Python, to round them both in one direction, say, to `0.2`? In other words, is there something analogous to `floor` or `ceil` for rounding to an integer, in the context of rounding to a certain number of decimal places?

Update: Accepting the solution based on `decimal` because it throws light on such a feature available in Python. The solutions based on dividing (and later multiplying) by a multiple of 10 are good ones and straightforward to use.

Comment: Do you mean to use floor?

Comment: By definition you can't round down, otherwise it wouldn't be rounding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) library:

```
from decimal import * 
print(Decimal(0.229).quantize(Decimal('.1'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN))
print(Decimal(0.251).quantize(Decimal('.1'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN))
```

Output:

```
0.2
0.2
```

You can also convert from `Decimal` to `float`:

```
f = float(Decimal(0.229).quantize(Decimal('.1'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)))
```

Comment: Note that [wildcard imports should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3615206/11021886) and are often considered bad practice

Comment: @Ralph Although your point is generally correct, but even the python documentation uses it this way. I think this is due to size and names of the functions in the module.

Comment: Fair enough. I concede that there are exceptions to this rule, and this certainly appears to be such a case!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `floor` as follows:

```
def round_down(x):
    return math.floor(10*x) / 10

print(round_down(0.229))
print(round_down(0.251))
```

This prints:

```
0.2
0.2
```

The logic here is to first multiply up by 10, which then lets `floor` round down all decimal components other than the first one.  Then, we divide again by 10 to generate the rounded-down number.

Answer (score 1):

There are already a couple of good answers to your question, however both solutions rely on external libraries. It is also possible to achieve what you desire with no imports:

```
def round_down(x):
    return int(10 * x) / 10

x = 0.251
round_down(x)
# 0.2
x = 0.229
round_down(x)
# 0.2
```

If you wanted something more similar to Python's round (where you can specify the number `n` of digits to round to), you could use:

```
def round_down(x, n=1):
    return int(10**n * x)  / 10**n

x = 0.229
round_down(x)
# 0.2
round_down(x, 2)
# 0.22
```

Depending how you'd like the rounding to behave for negative numbers, you may instead wish to define `round_down(x)` as:

```
def round_down(x):
    return 10 * x // 1 / 10
```