# Import multiple subdirectories/modules as if they are just one module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-import

so I have a module/directory called A and it has **init**.py file and in it, it has another module/directory called B which have its **init**.py and a file called function.py which has a function called dummy()

here is the structure of directories

```
A
|-- __init__.py
|
|-- B
    |
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- function.py
```

so what I want is to be on the same directory that contains directory A and do that

```
from A import *
dummy()
```

what I have done is do that in B/**init**.py

```
from dummy import *
```

and that in A/**init**.py

```
import B
```

and I can do that

```
from A.B import *
```

I want to write A instead of A.B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your import code a bit and it seems to work now like you wanted.
So in the B directory's init.py it has:

```
# __init__.py in B
from .function import *
```

In the A directory's init.py:

```
# __init__.py in A
from .B import *
```

Now, when I run Python shell in the directory that contains A and and use `from A import *`, it calls `dummy()` with no problem.

However, there are discussions on using wildcard imports in Python. Check this post for example: [Should wildcard import be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615125/should-wildcard-import-be-avoided#3615206)