# I'm getting 100 problems in vs code when importing tkinter

Tags: python

[image]

I'm having this problem in VS Code python when importing Tkinter
I have no idea what is this.

Comment: They're all warnings, how are they preventing you?

Comment: What what's hard to understand about the error message? If it's the "wildcard", read [python - Should wildcard import be avoided? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615125/should-wildcard-import-be-avoided)

Answer (score 0):

These are "just" warnings, which say you import a lot of modules via wildcard import (the * stands for import everything from tkinter).
You might be able to run the code though.

Alternatively you can only write

```py
import tkinter as tk
```

and then call your the subclasses etc. with a tk. before, as an example:

```py
root = tk.Tk()
```