# (python) Creating objects as modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a C developer and I have decided to pick up python as well. I can't to figure out why I am unable to create an instance of a class I made inside of a separate module. Here is my car.py module that contains my Car object

```
class Car:
    type = ""
    def __init__(self, type):
        self.type = type
```

And here is my other module that I am trying to use the Car object in

```
import car
x = Car()
print(x.type)
```

I get an error that says "Undefined variable 'Car' pylint(undefined-variable)" on the third line where I instantiate the car variable

I am also having trouble relocation the module to another directory within my project. The directory is named 'objects'. When I try to import the module, it says "No name 'car' in module 'objects' pylint(no-name-in-module)". Here is my import

```
from objects import car
```

Comment: Other answers have sorted out your import/module scoping related problem. You also need to pass a value for type when creating the object: x = Car(type).

Comment: Also, type is a built in function in Python so you should be careful that your use of it doesn’t shadow the built in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
import car

x = car.Car()
print(x.type)
```

Also, you can use:

```
from car import Car

x = Car()
print(x.type)
```

Comment: Or `from car import Car` and keep the code as before

Answer (score 1):

An `import` statement creates a reference to the named object in your namespace, loading the module that contains it if necessary. Modules are objects too.

```
import car
```

This statement creates a reference to the `car` module in your global namespace. The module object has a class object named `Car` as one of its attributes. You can access it with

```
x = car.Car()
```

You can import more selectively using the `from` keyword. That way, instead of creating a name `car` in your namespace, you can bind the name(s) you want directly:

```
from car import Car
```

With this form of the `import` statement, your code should work directly.

On a related note, you can also use the `as` keyword to change the name that the imported object gets bound to, as though with an assignment:

```
from car import Car as Auto

x = Auto()
```

or

```
import car as auto

x = auto.Car()
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating a module and importing it you to specify the namespace to create a instance

This can be done in two ways, specifying the namespace while creating the instance or making the namespace available to the whole file:

`from car import *` or `from car import Car` if you just want the car class.

then you can do `x = Car`

Alternatively you can import the module and specify the namespace while creating the instance:

```
import car
car = car.Car()
```

Comment: Please don't advise the OP to use `from car import *` -- it is not a good idea. [Should wildcard import be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615125/should-wildcard-import-be-avoided)