# Problem with using Tkinter in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, tkinter, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use Tkinter with Python in Visual Studio Code and its working fine except I get this yellow underline here:

[(code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M61L9.png)

and when I hover on it it shows a lot of stuff here:

[hovered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGGFb.png)

Answer (score 1):

In python there are different ways to import packages.

1. from ... import ... [as ...]
2. import ... [as ...]

In your example you use the first variant with a so-called wildcard. This means you’ll put all the names from the tkinter package into your global namespace. It would be better and is common to import tkinter with `import tkinter as tk` in order to maintain a certain encapsulation.

You then address objects from tkinter with tk.object_name.

Answer (score 1):

It's the design logic of `pylint`. If you want to solve it, you can take these methods:

1. You can switch to another linter, such as `mypy`,`pylama`,`flake8`
   and so on. But you will still encounter the warning of `unable to detect undefined names`.
2. Explicit the thing you want to import, such as: `from tkinter import Tk, Label`. This is recommended.
3. Add this in the settings.json file:

   *"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
   "--disable=all --enable=F,E,unreachable,duplicate-key,unnecessary-semicolon,global-variable-not-assigned,unused-variable,binary-op-exception,bad-format-string,anomalous-backslash-in-string,bad-open-mode,**unused-wildcard-import,wildcard-import**"
   ],*

   The beginning of the settings was the default setting of `pylint` in
   the VSCode, `unused-wildcard-import,wildcard-import` was set to
   remove warning of **wildcard**.

Comment: @Lockks hope to hear from you.

Comment: @Lockks Could you check this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615125/should-wildcard-import-be-avoided)?

Comment: @BlueNet And [this page](https://stevepython.wordpress.com/2019/01/12/how-to-avoid-wildcard-imports/)