# Django: 'TypeError: 'HttpResponseForbidden' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates

am building a portal for jobs. I encountered the error on the title. I have tried all suggested solution. None is resolving my problem.Kindly assist.The error has hold me hostage for the last 48 hrs.If a try to login ,admin,register or accessing any page, am getting

**'TypeError: 'HttpResponseForbidden' object is not callable**

Here is the model,views and templates:

**model_1**

```py
#models
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE
from PIL import Image


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pic')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self):
        super().save()     
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 300 and img.width > 300:
            output_size=(300,300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

**Views_1**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.http import request, HttpResponse
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import *
from .models import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CompRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            return redirect('Login')
    else:
        form = CompRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'Users/register.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = CompUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfilePicForm(request.POST,
                                request.FILES,
                                instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('Profile_Page')

    else:
        u_form = CompUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfilePicForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }

    return render(request, 'Users/profile.html', context)
```

**Templates**

```html
{% extends "../Job/base.html"%}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content%}
{% load bootstrap %}
<div class="container">
  <form method ="POST", enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {%csrf_token%}
    <fieldset>
      <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Login</legend> 
      {{form|bootstrap}}
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="Submit">Login </button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="border-top pt-3"> 
    <small class= "text-muted">
    Need an account ? <a class= 'ml-2' href="{% url 'Register' %}"> Sign up </a>
    </small>
    <small>
      Forgot Password ? <a class = 'ml-2' href="{% url 'password_reset'%}">Reset Password</a>
    </small>
  
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**Urls**

```py
from typing import Pattern
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from Users import views as user_views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('Job.urls')),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name="Register"),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='Users/login.html'), name='Login'),
    path('Logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='Users/index.html'), name='Logout'),
    path('profile/', user_views.Profile, name="Profile_Page"),
    path('Password-reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
        template_name='Users/password_reset.html'), name='password_reset'),
    path('Password-reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
        template_name='Users/password_reset_done.html'), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('Password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
        template_name='Users/password_reset_confirm.html'), name='password_reset_confirm'),
]


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**Error**

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tito/wira_Proj/wira_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
TypeError: 'HttpResponseForbidden' object is not callable
[31/Aug/2021 06:59:12] "GET /profile/ HTTP/1.1" 500 58968
Internal Server Error: /favicon.ico
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tito/wira_Proj/wira_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
TypeError: 'HttpResponseForbidden' object is not callable
```

***Your assistance will be highly appreciated***

Comment: Please [edit] and add the _full_ error traceback to your question.

Comment: Show your `urls.py` and do you have any custom middleware?

Comment: I have added URLS .  Custom middle ware,i am using Django pre-pack version

Comment: Typo: In `path('profile/', user_views.Profile, name="Profile_Page")` the `user_views.Profile` is referring to the _model_, your view is named `profile` hence it should be `user_views.profile`. Also see [Should wildcard import be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615125/should-wildcard-import-be-avoided)

Comment: Thank you for the correction. Unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: @TheElif can you add your forms too

Comment: @TheElif are you doing all this thing on your main projects urls.py

Comment: @TheElif if yes then i will highly recommend you to create an app and it that paste all your code becuase i also tried the same thing as a bignner and trust men that not gonna work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution:
Check the following in your settings.py file and remove/delete them

- CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN:The domain to be used when setting the CSRF cookie. This can be useful for easily allowing cross-subdomain requests to be excluded from the normal cross site request forgery protection. It should be set to a string such as ".example.com" to allow a POST request from a form on one subdomain to be accepted by a view served from another subdomain.
- CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE: Wnen you set to true it the cookie will be marked as “secure”, which means browsers may ensure that the cookie is only sent with an HTTPS connection.And remember you are working on a localhost
- django.views.csrf.csrf_failure

Read more from [django Crosssite Forgery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf)

Answer (score 0):

in your views try this

```
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = CompUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfilePicForm(request.POST,
                                request.FILES,
                                instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('Profile_Page')

    else:
        u_form = CompUpdateForm()
        p_form = ProfilePicForm()

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }

    return render(request, 'Users/profile.html', context)
```