# AttributeError: module 'tk' has no attribute 'Tk'

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

It seem like `pip install tkinter` has been renamed to `pip install tk`. But when I try to run it, this happens:

```
AttributeError: module 'tk' has no attribute 'Tk'
```

This is my Code:

```
import tk 
from tk import *

base = Tk()
## base = tk.Tk() does not work as well
```

Also, there is no file in my directory named `tkinter` or `tk` and on Tkinter page has no mention about the change. Is anyone facing the same issue?

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what to install with `pip` (I used `apt`), but AFAIK the module is still called `tkinter`, so `from tkinter import *`. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing two different things [tkinter built-in module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) and [tk external module](https://pypi.org/project/tk/), second is *TensorKit is a deep learning helper between Python and C++.*
You should do

```
from tkinter import *
base = Tk()
```

Consult linked docs if you want to know more

Comment: It's not advised to use `from tkinter import *`. It's better to use `import tkinter as tk`

Comment: @TheLizzard I lifted `from tkinter import *` verbatim from [python tkinter docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html)

Comment: @Daweo The docs actually use `import tkinter as tk` in the simple hello world example. Also please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3615125/11106801)

Answer (score 0):

If you still have problems, one nasty corner case is if you call your file `tkinter.py`. It won't find the actual module with the same name.