# Tkinter: Use Frame from another class

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am practicing to create a small project with different files to have a clean code.  I want to show yellow frame from (**fyellow.py**) into (**main.py**) and input a label into it from (**funbut.py**) using  `Button`'s function. This is my code example: (3 Python files - **main.py**, **fyellow.py**, and **funbut.py**)

- **main.py**

  ```
  from tkinter import *
  from fyellow import *
  import funbut

  root = Tk()
  root.geometry("500x500")

  # Show Yellow Frame into Main from (fyellow.py)
  myframe = Frameyellow(root)

  # Button with command - But_fun1
  but1 = Button(root, text="Text",command=funbut.but_fun1)
  but1.pack()


  root.mainloop()
  ```
- **funbut.py**

  ```
  from tkinter import *
  from fyellow import *

  # Function of Button (but1) PROBLEM HERE! (ERROR - 'framey' is not defined)
  def but_fun1():
      label1 = Label(framey,text="LabelText")
      label1.place(x=10,y=10)
  ```
- **fyellow.py**

  ```
  from tkinter import *

  class Frameyellow:
      def __init__(self,rootyellow):
          self.rootyellow = rootyellow
          self.framey = Frame(rootyellow, width=200,height=200,bg="yellow")
          self.framey.pack()
  ```

Could explain what can I do to use the `self.framey` from file (**fyellow.py**) to avoid
error `'framey' is not defined`?

Comment: well.... `framey` is not defined, do you see any place where it is defined? use function arguments to pass master to that label, also `myframe` is not a `Frame`

Comment: Kindly could you please arrange my code how can I do it  ? I appreciate your help so much. @Matiiss

Comment: Kindly could you please recommend to me , any online links or books for python Tkinter ? (From beginner to Professional )  I am watching you tube videos .. @Matiiss

Comment: well you can search for documentation for specific libraries if you need but otherwise if you are a beginner just keep on watching youtube, if you want to learn more I would also suggest practice which this pretty much is, take a look at what other people have made and maybe learn from them if that is what you were asking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `main.py` file would look like this:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button
from fyellow import FrameYellow
from funbut import place_label

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

my_frame = FrameYellow(root)
my_frame.pack()

but1 = Button(root, text="Text", command=lambda: place_label(my_frame))
but1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

`fyellow.py` like this (tho kinda pointless to create a class whose sole purpose is to have the frame a different color, just use arguments and create a normal frame):

```py
from tkinter import Frame


class FrameYellow(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs, bg='yellow')
```

and `funbut.py` should be sth like this:

```py
from tkinter import Label


def place_label(parent, text='Text', pos=(0, 0)):
    Label(parent, text=text).place(x=pos[0], y=pos[1])
```

Also:
I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

Comment: @Loro Bil: Also see [Should wildcard import be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615125/should-wildcard-import-be-avoided)