# How can I only accept user entry for a minute in tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
window = Tk()
e = Entry(window, width=100)
e.pack()
player2 = ""

def get_text():
    e.config(state='disabled')
    player2 = e.get()
    return player2

Button(window, text="done", command=get_text).pack()

t = 60
for x in range(t):
    t = t -1
    time.sleep(1)

if t == 0:
    Label(window, text="Times up").pack()
    e.config(state='disabled')
    player2 = e.get()
Label(window, text=player2).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Here is my code, but its not really working. I would like to create an entry and let user only enter words only for one minute, unless the button done is pressed then the entry value is stored in a variable called player2.

Comment: The timer should run in parallel. You may need some library for a timer. Timer should start and either the timer should run for 1 minute or until the user presses done.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#introduction). To solve your question you need the [after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753632/tkinter-how-to-use-after-method) method of tkinter, everything else is discouraged. Also see why you need to [seperate your construction from your geometry method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name). Also Why to [avoid wildcard imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615125/should-wildcard-import-be-avoided).

```
from tkinter import *

def get_text():
    e.config(state='disabled')
    my_label.configure(text=e.get())

def after_time():
    my_label.configure(text="Times up")#configure instead of new
    e.config(state='disabled')
    
window = Tk()

e = Entry(window, width=100)
e.pack()

my_button = Button(window, text="done", command=get_text)
my_button.pack()

my_label = Label(window, text='..waiting for username..') #seperate construction from geometry
my_label.pack()

window.after(1000, after_time) #after(ms,function)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will disable the inputfield within one minute:

```py
from threading import Timer
def disable():
    Label(window, text="Times up").pack()
    e.config(state='disabled')
    player2 = e.get()
Timer(60,disable).start()
```

Do also not that returning player2 in your get_text() function won't do anything. You won't change the variable outside the function. You should save your label and use `config` to set its text.

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code a bit in order to do the same, hope this is what you were aiming to do.

```
import threading
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
window = Tk()
e = Entry(window, width=100)
e.pack()
player2 = ""

def get_text():
    e.config(state='disabled')
    global player2
    player2 = e.get()
    return player2

Button(window, text="done", command=get_text).pack()

def logic():
    global player2
    Label(window, text="Times up").pack()
    e.config(state='disabled')
    player2 = e.get()
threading.Timer(60.0, logic).start()

Label(window, text=player2).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Tk().after`

```py
root = Tk()
root.after(1000, function)
# 1000 = 1 Second
```