# Can't close a window and keep other open

Tags: python, tkinter, destroy

I am trying to open a second window and then run some code and close the second window on the button event. I have tried every example that I can find and I still get an attribute error. I am pretty new to this.

I stripped out most of the code so that it's easier to read.

```
#   ADD NEW PASSWORD
def add_pass():

    add_pass = Toplevel()
    add_pass.title("Enter New Password")
    add_pass.geometry('500x700')
    # add_pass.resizable(0, 0)

    
    Add_Button = Button(add_pass, text="Enter", font=("normal", 14), 
    command=add_butt)
    Add_Button.grid(row=12, column=2, pady=30)
    
    
def add_butt():

    print(Person_Entry.get())

    # Create a database or connect to one
    conn = sqlite3.connect('Pass.db')

    c = conn.cursor()                
                        
    # WRITE TEXT BOXES TO SQLITE3 DB USING VARIABLES. 
    PassData = [(Seq_Entry.get(), Person_Entry.get(), Name_Entry.get(), 
    URL_Entry.get(), Username_Entry.get(), Password_Entry.get(), Hint1_Entry.get(), 
    Hint2_Entry.get(), Hint3_Entry.get(), Notes_Entry.get())]
    
    for element in PassData:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO Passwords VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", 
    element)
        

    # Commit Changes
    conn.commit()

    # Close Connection
    conn.close()

    add_pass.destroy()

root = Tk()

root.geometry('500x500')
root.title('Password Saver')
my_menu = Menu(root)
 

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got several options here to achieve this, the easiest way to go would be to use [lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62742314) and pass a reference of your window, stored with the variable `add_pass` in the [namespace](https://medium.com/@gough.cory/understanding-python-namespaces-through-recursion-c921cbd4e522) of the function `add_pass` through the interface of your function `add_butt`. [Passing an argument through a button command in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6920302) can be achieved in different ways but I prefer lambda.

The changes would look like this:

```
def add_pass(): 
    ..
    Add_Button = Button( ..,command=lambda window=add_pass: add_butt(window))

def add_butt(window):
    window.destroy()
   ...
```

Addition advice:

Don't use wildcard imports

Don't use the same variable name more than once

[See explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3615206)
And also take a look at [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: You are awesome!!! I have been struggling with that for a few days now. It worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: @Ken you are welcome. Please also take a look at the links I have provided. If you understand the context you will make greater progress. I also recommend this [tkinter tutorial](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6lxxT7IdTxGoHfouzEK-dFcwr_QClME_) with I have start with programming. Merry Christmas.