# Python Image Library and Tkinter Clashing

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have an issue where PIL and Tkinter are not working together in the same program.

Basically, I tried to run my program and when it was on the line 'image.open()' it thought I was trying to call tkinter's image.open function and not PIL's because both Tk and PIL have the same 'image.' functions.

Mainly what I want to know is if there is a way to restrict tkinter from accessing a part of my code.

Comment: [Does this answers your question ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3615206/13629335)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out this was actually not happening. I just had to change the image mode for it to work.