# How to write a simple code to do float calculation in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to write a code for this calculation:

> 3.3+4.8*6-4/2

Here is my code:

```
from decimal import *
a = Decimal('3.3') + Decimal('4.8') * 6
b = 4 / 2
c = a - Decimal(str(b))
print(c)
```

The above code can give the right answer: 30.1. But I think it is too complex and there should be a simpler solution. Can anyone give a simplified code?
Thanks.

Comment: Something interesting to note is that: `48*60/100-4/2+3.3` gives the desired output~

Comment: You have alll constants. Simpy do `print("30.1")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your provided calculation it is not clear if you will use different variables in it or if you want to evaluate just this one particular equation.
If you want to compute just this equation, compute "(3.3 + 4.8 * 6.0) - 2.0" because you do not really need calculator for 4/2. So simply:

```
result = 3.3 + 4.8 * 6.0 - 2.0
print(round(result, 2)) #round() to "render" floating-point error
```

But if it will be used many times for different variables, you should define a function, e.g. (suppose all numbers in the equation are variables):

```
def eq_evaluation(a, b, c, d, e):
    return round((a + b * c - d / e), 2)
```

Also wildcard import (`from package import *`) is not a best practice in python. See for example: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615125/should-wildcard-import-be-avoided) about it.

Comment: `round()` might be a good option. I just want to find a way to avoid floating-point issue.

Comment: Why use `round()` instead of f-strings? https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings

Comment: I just assumed that OP would want to keep return value as a float instead of string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming python 3:

```py
print(3.3+4.8*6-4/2)
# 30.099999999999994
print('{:.2f}'.format(3.3+4.8*6-4/2))
# 30.10
```

Comment: I am using Python 3, the result is 30.099999999999994.

Comment: @TomLiu And this is the right answer. This is how float work. If you want a rounded answer, round it. I'll edit the answer.