# TypeError unhashable type 'list'

Tags: python-3.x, list, typeerror, binary-search

I'm attempting a binary search problem from leetcode and this is my code below (ignore if it's not the proper implementation, i'd like to figure it out myself):

```
class Solution:
    def search(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        middle = int(len(nums)/2)
        ind = -1
        
        if(nums[middle] == target):
            return ind
        elif (nums[middle] > target):
            ind = middle
            nums = nums[:middle-1]
            print(nums)
            search(nums, target)
        else:
            ind = middle
            nums = nums[middle:len(nums)-1]
            print(nums)
            search(nums, target)
```

I'm trying to get my code to recurse using a slice of a list, but I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
return _cache[type(pattern), pattern, flags]
Line 293 in _compile (/usr/lib/python3.10/re.py)
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
Line 200 in search (/usr/lib/python3.10/re.py)
    search(nums, target)
Line 17 in search (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().search(param_1, param_2)
Line 42 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 53 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

I don't understand what this means in regards to search(nums,targets).

Comment: Side-note: Never use `int(len(nums)/2)`, just use `len(nums) // 2` and avoid degrading to `float` in the first place (`//` with `int` operands is purely `int` floor division).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code, somewhere, is doing `from re import search` (or, [*shudders*, `from re import *`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3615125/364696)) at global scope. You then fail to properly invoke `search` on `self`, so it finds the `re` module function and calls that instead. As a bonus error, you're not returning the values from your recursive calls, so any time you recurse you end up returning `None`. The fixes are pretty simple at least, just change:

```
search(nums, target)
```

to:

```
return self.search(nums, target)
```

invoking the correct `search` method on `self`, and returning what it returns. The fix must be made in both places you're making the recursive call.

Comment: Related reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615125/should-wildcard-import-be-avoided

Comment: @SuperStormer: Link incorporated into answer, with personal commentary. :-)