# TypeError: object is not callable when solving for 1st order ODEs?

Tags: python, typeerror, sympy, ode

This is the code I've written and been provided with, and below is the error I am repeatedly getting. I've tried using both `y.diff` & `Derivative` functions in this code, but both of them give me the same error.

```py
#y'-2ty = -t
from sympy import *

t = symbols('t')
y = Function('y')(t)

eqn = (Derivative(y(t)) - (2*t*y(t)), -t)
display(eqn)

ysol = dsolve(eqn,y(t))
print("The solution is ", ysol.lhs, " = ", ysol.rhs)
print("The solution is ") 
display(ysol)
```

Error:

```
----> 1 ysol = dsolve(eqn,y(t))

TypeError: 'y' object is not callable
```

Comment: You should not use `y(t)` in the equation, just use `y`.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```py
y = Function('y')(t)
```

already defines `y` as a function of `t`. When you write `y(t)` later, you're asking sympy to call `y` as if it's a function (like when you call the `print` function as `print(...)`). You have two options: (1) Don't define `y` as a function of `t`, i.e.

```py
y = Function('y')
```

With that change, you will no longer get the error. (2) Keep `y` defined as it is but later only write `y` instead of `y(t)`, i.e.

```py
eqn = (Derivative(y) - (2*t*y), -t)
```

In your question you said you tried `y.diff()`, but with how you've defined `y`, that should actually work, so I'm guess you actually did `y(t).diff()`.

---

Now, you actually have another issue later, which is that you should define `eqn` as a sympy equation, i.e.

```py
eqn = Eq(Derivative(y) - (2*t*y), -t)
```

Without that, `dsolve` will throw an error (it's expecting an equation).

---

As another minor point, [avoid wildcard imports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3615206/12131013) (`from X import *`) in your code. Some people will do `import sympy as smp` or `import sympy as sp` or just `import sympy`. Then, you would do `y = smp.Function("y")`.